# Error adding UITableView to ViewController on storyboard

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitableview

On my `storyboard` I have a `ViewController` and I want to add a `UITableView` with 1 section and 2 static cells. That's all I'm doing right now but I get this error when compiling.

```
Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

Look at [This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277473/want-to-create-a-cool-static-ui-but-static-table-views-are-only-valid). Basically the same thing.

Any further questions, just ask! :)

Edited stuff:

```
    UITableViewController *controller = [[UITableViewController alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewStylePlain];
[self.view addSubview:controller.tableView];
```

Then all you need to do is adding the UITableViewDataSource in the header file and you need the datasource methods:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView{
return 1;
}
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section{
return 2;
}
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
if([indexPath row] = 0){
do something
}else if([indexPath row] = 1){
do something else
}
```

Comment: The answer mentions to "Add a UITableViewController to your view." I can add a UITableView to a view but how would I add a UITableViewController to a view?

Comment: Hmm... Guess you would have to add it programmatically.
Changing my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I think you just have to set datasource and delegate methods of the tableView in your .h file

```
@interface viewController : UIViewController<UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>
```

and then link it to your tableView in storyboard.

Please notify if it works..

Comment: Wasn't this what you couldn't do with static tableviews? Haven't tried it myself, but the topic and my linked question seems to imply that...