# Table with static cells in UISplitViewController detail view

Tags: ios, objective-c, ipad, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller

I have developed an iPhone app which I am trying to port to iPad using UISplitViewController. The iPhone app is an ideal candidate for "Master-detail view" design. The master view shows a list of things and clicking on each row opens up its detail in the detail view. However, my problem is that I need the detail view to contain a static table containing 5 cells. I am unable to figure out how to put a static table in the detail view of the UISplitViewController. I tried the following:

1. Created a master-detail storyboard
2. Set up the detail view controller's class as a custom class derived from UITableViewController. This is the same class which I am using in my iPhone code for the main screen.
3. Dragged a table view in the detail view
4. Configured the detail view to show static cells

As soon as I change the cells to static, I get an error "Static table views are only valid when embedded in UITableViewController instances".

I am unable to understand what this error means and how to configure static cells in detail view. What should I do?

I am relatively new to iOS programming and have been struggling for past 2 days on this problem.

Comment: I knew, I heard it... [check it](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9277570/3831935), may help...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error means that in order to use static cells, you have to have a `UITableViewController`. It is not enough to use a `UIViewController` and add a `UITableView` to it. What I would do is to add a `container view` to my detail, and embed a `UITableViewController` in it (ctrl+drag -  embed segue), that way the `UITableViewController` becomes `childViewController` of your detail VC and you can change it when you tap a different cell in the master.

If you don't want to change it, then just delete the `detail` part suggested by the storyboard, and add an instance of `UITableViewController`.

**Edit:**

Here is my setup that I just tried, and it works. The right most screen in the picture is a subclass of `UITableViewController`. When you add a `Container view` to your detail, it adds a `UIViewController` automatically. Delete that and add a `UITableViewController`.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I am still not clear. I did like you suggested. Added container view to the detail view, but that did nothing. It just created another view controller down the chain. I am missing something very obvious. Can you provide step-by-step guide in more detail? Thanks again for your help.

Comment: The screenshot was very helpful. Thank you very much. It is working now. I also had to fix the storyboard file in build configs at a couple of places to fix one nasty exception.